# Salesforce Marketing Cloud (Exact Target) Limits

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect

Just wondering if anyone aware of Marketing Cloud Limits, for example:

Any Activity Limit (import, query, Filter etc).

Any Data Extension /Custom object/ Lists  limits.

Emails.

Any Automation Limits.

Comment: > I am using Salesforce data as an "entry event" for a journey > I can NOT select a specific field as "event data". It's a text field with 130'000 characters. Do you know why? What are limitations there?

Comment: Please add more details? Most limitations are found in the contract, unless you are looking for some of the concrete solution limits? I.e. limits in processing time for JB Custom Activities? Run time for single activities in the automations? other?

Answer (score 1):

Yes there are, but they're a bit obtuse to find and locate. They're also a bit difficult for me to provide the various links to them for you here as they're a bit spotty in the documentation. One of them has to do with [Data Stream Limits](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000233192&language=en_US). Others can be found in the [Salesforce App Cloud API Services Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce1api.meta/salesforce1api/apex_gov_limits.htm). I recommend you use http://FINDSF.INFO and the search term "marketing cloud limits" to locate them.