# Resource limits when sending to 30k+?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, lookup

I have an AmpScript that does 2 DE lookups, once for each of two DEs, and 1 upsert to one of those DEs, in a script that is around 140 lines. We have a target list of up to 100k target email addresses and I think it's timing out around 30k.

My question is, should I be able to use an AmpScript like this in an email template that goes out to up to 100k users, or are 2 lookups and 1 upsert too much for that many targets?

Thanks!

Comment: Check out: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/126134/salesforce-marketing-cloud-exact-target-limits#126189

Comment: What's the business case for upserting in an email?  Most of the time what you need to do can be done with a query activity in an Automation or utilizing the SendLog after the send.

Comment: Currently, I'm monitoring opens for multiple emails using measures and filters and updating an 'opens' DE using SQL queries. That's one of the lookups in each email. The other lookup and upsert are for a 'cooldowns' DE, recording which message gets used in each email for each email address. In each email template using AmpScript, I lookup which messages are on cooldown. I worry that this way of doing it is too taxing on the system.

Answer (score 0):

I sometimes use 150 line Ampscript with lots of Lookups in it, even with some Math functions, and send the emails to the audiences around 1M. Because the system sends the emails batch by batch in half an hour, it doesn't create any problems for me.